# Billing for api calls with a provided client/UI

Tags: billing, metering

I have a general question regarding the approach of metering/billing.

We have a service and want to meter via api calls as well as have an optional reusable javascript UI component which customers can use. This UI component is a reusable one and has to be used by the leading UI web application.

This UI component internally makes call to the service using the same APIs.

For API integration api calls metering will be straight forward because the APIs will be used by the clients used/developed by the consumer.

How should the metering happen for the UI component because the UI component is internally making API calls. Do we need to have a separate commercialisation model for the UI consumption ?

Best Regards,

Saurav

Answer (score 0):

> This UI component internally makes call to the service using the same
>   APIs.

You **can't** distinguish between the API calls *your* client made and therefore are not to be billed and the ones by *any* other user of the API endpoint.

The only way to I can think of you could achieve this is to **embed some kind of secret into your client** that can be presented to the server with the *non billing* requests. That is something that **anyone** with a rudimentary knowledge of how stuff works **can find out**.

That is why I would recommend to find a billing metric other than calls (requests):

- Time (monthly/annualy)
- Users
- Volume (requests per time)

I know that there is always a business guy that thinks *no one has enough criminal energy to circumvent the system like this*…

**Do not compromise** (you'll pay in the end...)

Comment: Thanks for your inputs...other metrics may not work out for us. We have technical user based flow so can't have users as a metric...I want to keep even our UI in the billing game

Comment: I totally understand your requirement, but I'm afraid if you don't want to change your overall design to accommodate a way to differentiate the requests on the server side you are left with **obfuscation** on the client side.